# Android Recycler view with grid cards

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a recycler view with cards arranged linearly like this: This is my current interface, I need help with a mixed view as shown in the second image

[image: My interface]

but i need a mixed view with grids like this: This is my target interface
[image: target interface]

**I need help achieving this:
This is what i have tried so far
**card.axml****

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp">
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
            android:layout_margin="6dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/avatar2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="160dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/cheese_1" />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="16dp">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/Text11"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:maxLines="2"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/Text12"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:maxLines="3"
                        android:textColor="#555" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="share"
                        android:theme="@style/PrimaryFlatButton" />
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="explore"
                        android:theme="@style/PrimaryFlatButton" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**My Recycler view adapter**

```
public class SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
        {

            private List<Data> mValues;


            Context context;

            public SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<Data> items)
            {
                this.context = context;
                mValues = items;

            }

            public override int ItemCount
            {

                get
                {
                    return mValues.Count();
                }
            }

            public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
            {
                if (holder is SimpleViewHolder)
                    try
                    {
                        Data item = mValues.ElementAt(position);

                        var simpleHolder = holder as SimpleViewHolder;

                        simpleHolder.mTxtView.Text = Android.Text.Html.FromHtml(item.article.Title).ToString();
                        simpleHolder.mTxtView2.Text = item.article.Description;


                        using (var imageView = simpleHolder.mImageView)
                        {
                            string url = Android.Text.Html.FromHtml(item.article.UrlToImage).ToString();

                            //Download and display image
                            UrlImageViewHelper.SetUrlDrawable(imageView,
                                url, Resource.Drawable.cheese_1
                                );



                        }
                        //    simpleHolder.mprogressbar.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        //Toast.MakeText(this.context, e.ToString(), ToastLength.Long).Show();
                    }



            }

            public override int GetItemViewType(int position)
            {

                    return Resource.Layout.ItemsList;



            }



            public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
            {
                if (viewType == Resource.Layout.ItemsList)
                {
                    View view = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.ItemsList, parent, false);
                    view.SetBackgroundColor(Color.White);


                    SimpleViewHolder holder = new SimpleViewHolder(view);
                    // holder.mprogressbar = view.FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.progressBar);
                    // holder.mprogressbar.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;


                    //Showing loading progressbar

                    return holder;
                }

            }
        }

        public class SimpleViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        {
            public string mBoundString;
            public readonly View mView;
            public readonly ImageView mImageView;
            public readonly TextView mTxtView;
            public readonly TextView mTxtView2;
            //   public ProgressBar mprogressbar;


            public SimpleViewHolder(View view) : base(view)
            {
                mView = view;
                mImageView = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.avatar2);
                mTxtView = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Text11);
                mTxtView2 = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Text12);
                //   mprogressbar = view.FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.progressBar);


            }


        }
```

**setupRecyclerView method**

```
 private async void SetUpRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView)
            {
      Activity.RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {

 dataUse = OfflineDeserializer.OfflineData(content, json2);

                recyclerView.SetLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(recyclerView.Context));
                recyclerView.SetAdapter(new SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter(recyclerView.Context, dataUse));
                if (vp.IsShown)
                {
                    vp.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;

                }
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i need help creating grid cards as shown in the second image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `SetUpRecyclerView` method, use a `GridLayoutManager` instead of `LinearLayoutManager`, with a span count of 2 and then call `SetSpanSizeLookup` on the layout manager. With your custom span size lookup you can determine which items will span the whole layout.

A quick example:

```
SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter myAdapter = new SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter(recyclerView.Context, dataUse)
GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(recyclerView.Context, 2);
layoutManager.SetSpanSizeLookup(new SpanSizeLookup(myAdapter));
recyclerView.SetLayoutManager(layoutManager);
recyclerView.SetAdapter(myAdapter);
```

And the `SpanSizeLookup` class:

```
internal class SpanSizeLookup : GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup
{
    private SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter _adapter;
    public SpanSizeLookup(SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter adapter) => _adapter = adapter;
    public override int GetSpanSize(int position)
    {
        return _adapter.GetItemViewType(position);
    }
}
```

In your `SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter` class override `GetItemViewType` in a way like this, that conforms with how you decide which items span the full width; I use a `IsHeader` bool here but you can use whatever you wish:

```
public override int GetItemViewType(int position)
{
    if(mValues[position].IsHeader)
         return 1;
    else
         return 2;
}
```

You could also customize it further by returning an enum with `GetItemViewType` and decide on the span count in the `SpanSizeLookup`.

Comment: Thanks, solved the problem already, followed the same step. Will mark as answer

Answer (score 0):

I Just Have Used this line to my code to make it work
GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, 3);